# Save user choices in Array in multiple mxml

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I'm building a simple application with Flash Builder. I'm using an API to collect sport player names. When they find these players they get to see some stats and have a button to add them to their follow list.

Now I dont want to use a database just yet but I want to save their "choice" in a temporary array and then re-use it in another mxml so they can see the different players. The array would concist of their id's.

Now my question is, how do I allow my array to be used in multiple mxml files? Does bubbling work or maybe there is a better solution then an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use singletons with '`bindable`' collection objects. so, it can be accessible through out the application, (make it look like an mvc framework)

other way

You can even use `custom events` to do that. listen and throw events on the `FlexGlobal.topLevelApplication` so, you dont miss events.